# Javascript href attribute for css not updating

Tags: javascript

I am learning jquery and to test out my skills, I created a button that could switch styles with jquery, but that dosen't work for some reason. any ideas?
Code:

```html
<link id="original" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://style.es.cx/style2.css">
<script>
function turnGrey(){
    document.getElementById("original").href="http://style.es.cx/style.css";<!-- what ever your new css file is called-->
}
</script>
<button id="grey" onclick="turnGrey">Turn Grey</button><br />
<pre>this text should change</pre>
<div>
    foobar
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Where do you use jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of mistakes.

1. You are using vanilla javascript, not jQuery (you include the library but the syntax used is not jQuery).
2. Your function doesn't work since you are not calling it. You are writing `onclick="turnGrey"` when it needs to be `onclick="turnGrey()"`.
3. Change the stylesheet is not the good practice. It's better change the classname.
4. The comments in javascript are like this: `/* comment */`. You are writing a comment in HTML inside a javascript code, that crashes completely your code.

However, here you are the code that could works (I remove jQuery library since you are not using don't eat machine resources):

---

```html
<link id="original" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://style.es.cx/style2.css">
<script>
function turnGrey(){
    document.getElementById("original").href="http://style.es.cx/style.css"; /* what ever your new css file is called */
}
</script>
<button id="grey" onclick="turnGrey()">Turn Grey</button><br />
<pre>this text should change</pre>
<div>
foobar
</div>
```

Comment: _You are using vanilla javascript, not jQuery_.....doesn't seem to be a mistake. also #3 is not a mistake too.

Comment: In the original post, this question was about jquery. But the only jquery code that is here is the library including. So in my opinion is a mistake. However you're right in the point #3, it's not a mistake but change a color loading a new css file is a very bad practice (in my head is a mistake). If OP is learning javascript, will be better if we advice for this topics to avoid that OP can make it again. Thank you for your comment @Jai !

Answer (score 2):

You have to call the function with `()`:

```
 onclick="turnGrey()"
```

and `<!-- what ever your new css file is called-->` this is not the way to have a comment in `<script>`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `turnGrey()` is a function, but in your `onclick` you just have the function name.  You aren't actually calling the function.  Change `onclick="turnGrey"` to `onclick="turnGrey()"` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

What are you doing? By the way this is one way to change css.
or you can add or remove class also

`$("#grey").removeClass("success").addClass("danger");`

```html
<link id="original" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://style.es.cx/style2.css">
<script>
function turnGrey(){
    $("#grey").css('color', 'red');
    $("#grey").css('background-color', 'green');
}
</script>
<button id="grey" onclick="turnGrey()">Turn Grey</button><br />
<pre>this text should change</pre>
<div>
foobar
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```